# How to get aria-current in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, wai-aria

There is this property, `aria-current` in a NavLink, it is set is set to value page (`aria-current="page"` for the selected element).

Is there a way to access it in React? In order to change the styling for the other links which aren't selected.

Comment: It's possible, by using refs and querying the DOM … but you're approaching the problem backwards. Whatever logic you use to set the attribute in the first place (typically reading from a state) should be used to determine the other styling too.

Comment: see my answer below, shouldn't you have a uniform style for the ones that aren't selected & then have a specific style for the one that is selected? I think this is what @Quentin is also alluding to...

Answer (score 1):

See below, this is what I do with styled components with react router v6. But you can follow the same way of doing things with any other styling strategy.

```
const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  text-decoration: ${(props) => {
    console.log(props.style);
    return props.style ? (isActive) => (isActive ? "underline" : "none") : "none";
  }};
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
 &[aria-current] {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Or, as shown below, one can check for existence of the active class

```
const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
    text-decoration: ${(props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return props.style ? (isActive) => (isActive ? "underline" : "none") : "none";
  }}; 
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
 &[class*="active"] {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Comment: This answer worked for me.
chakra UI approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71885925/6907703

Answer (score 0):

Could this be done more easily with CSS?

`.navLink:not([aria-current]) { color: red;}`

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can access it via a ref of the element. For example:

```js
const navRef = useRef(null);


...

return <nav ref={navRef}>{navRef.current.ariaCurrent}</nav>
```

Just a heads up: Attributes that start with `aria` are only intended for accessibility purposes so I wouldn't rely on them for the styling of components.

Comment: That's one of the great things about ARIA attributes is that they can be used like any other attribute and referenced in CSS.  You might want a different style based on the value or existence of `aria-current`.  It's a great way to style things to help with accessibility.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can access it using useRef, and do whatever you want.